# new to scripting. need jar to run with on a large list of files

Tags: bash, shell, jar

I have a runnable jar file that takes a .txt file in argument. I need to run the jar for all my files but there is a million of them so I need to script it.

my folder containing all my files looks like this

```
WC-10-10-01.txt
WC-10-10-02.txt
WC-10-10-03.txt
WC-10-20-01.txt
WC-10-20-02.txt
WC-10-20-03.txt
```

so if I were to run it manually I would type these commands one by one

```
java -jar dynamique.jar -f /stuff/WC-10-10-01.txt

java -jar dynamique.jar -f /stuff/WC-10-10-02.txt

java -jar dynamique.jar -f /stuff/WC-10-10-03.txt
```

etc.

also the jar prints a result in console. I need to save each result in a single folder, lets say myResults.txt

Comment: Do you have the source code of your java project? If so, why don't you change it to iterate de files and save its results? This would be faster once you don't create one instance of JVM per call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the files in the directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in /example/directory/*.txt; do
    java -jar dynamique.jar -f "$filename" >> /home/sscripts/myResults.txt
done
```

Then you need to run the script from the directory it is stored, so if you save this script as **my_loop.sh** in the directory **/home/user/scripts/** you need to run it either:

```
$ cd /home/user/scripts/
$ ./my_script.sh
```

or from any directory:

```
$ /home/user/scripts/./my_script.sh
```

Remember to give runninf permission:

```
$ chmod +x /home/user/scripts/my_script.sh
```

---

A better approach would be to list the files yourself coding it in Java, rather than calling the jar with each filename. But that depends on you.